# Why is nginx not intercepting errors enve with proxy_intercept_errors on?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I'm setting proxy_intercept_errors on but nginx is not intercepting the 404 sent back from the server.

Any thoughts on what I should try?

```
 error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.html;
 location = /error.html {
         ssi on;
         internal;
 }

 location / {

            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_set_header host __THE HOST__;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass https://__THE IP__$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: Your question mentions 404, your code fragment contains 418, and you do not show the @search block. Can you expand the question?

Comment: @RichardSmith I just removed the 418 because that is unrelated to this question. I also added the error_page section that is relevant to this issue.